# how to share files over local network in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, network-shares

I am trying to paste some files from my laptop to desktop. both have ubuntu.  From the laptop I can see the desktop under Places -> Network.  I can see the files in the Desktop but when I try to paste a file it says "permission denied"

What can I do on the Desktop so it allows my laptop to paste files?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you've to configure the Folder sharing service (samba).

1. Click on the folder you wish to share with the right mouse button.
2. Select Sharing Options.
3. Select Share this folder.
4. If you would like people accessing the shared folder to be able to add, change and remove files in the folder, check Allow other people to write in this folder. Otherwise, people will only be able to view files in the folder.
5. If you would like to give access to users who do not have an account on your computer, **check Guest access**. Otherwise, people will only be able to browse the folder if they have such an account.
6. Press Create Share.

[image]